# Trigger a Kubernetes Job without having Kubernetes Installed

Tags: kubernetes

I want to give the ability to trigger a K8s to a person that doesn't work with IT. He doesn't have docker nor K8s installed.

What are my options to grant him this possibility ?

I already thinked I can create a custom service with POST endpoint with a basic auth that should allow him to make the query only with curl / postman, but I wonder if there is any "easier" and free alternative.

PD: This person has an account on gitlab.com and our K8s cluster is integrated to Gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

Does the company use some CI/CD tool that requires company authentication, supports authorization, and has a browser-based GUI (e.g. Jenkins)? If "yes", then create a job in that CI/CD tool that will connect to Kubernetes behind the scene using a Kubernetes service account to trigger the Kubernetes Job.

This way, the non-IT user won't have to know the any of the Kubernetes details, will use their company login credentials, will be restricted to trigger just this job, while using a browser GUI.

Comment: We use gitlab ci, it could be a way, let me check it !

Comment: I am in holidays, will try it when I get back!

Comment: Did you had time to test it? still need help?

Answer (score 0):

He/She/They can directly talk to kubernetes api server using curl etc. Easier way would be to install a client side tool like `kubectl` using which the other person can create the jobs.

You would need to provide them with credentials with appropriate access(limiting to creating jobs).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CI/CD tool like Jenkins or Gitlab CI to build a pipeline , which will internally connects to Kubernetes and perform any JOB you configured in that pipeline.

Comment: how is this answer different from the one provided by @gears?